# Alcohol in food

Tags: food, alcohol

I want to know weather beer battered fish is halal or haram?
Beer battered fish can never get you intoxicated, even if you eat 100 of them. Therefore, does the hadith: 'whatever intoxicates in large quantities is haram in low quantities'apply, given that the fish doesn't intoxicate in large quantities? I read a few fatwas on your website and they where quiet contradicting so i'm being as specific as i can to understand as much as possible.